# Java 8 Stream - Syntax error on token "(", Expression expected after this token

Tags: java

I have not used any Java 8.

Here is the code that I wrote below Java 8 Version.

```
List<GetOrderResponseType> orders = findOrderResponseType.getOrder();       
List<GetOrderResponseType> openOrders = new ArrayList<GetOrderResponseType>();

if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(orders)) { 
            for(GetOrderResponseType order : orders ) {     
                if ( order != null) {
                    if (order.getOrderSummary() != null) {
                        if ( order.getOrderSummary().getState() != null) {

                            if (order.getOrderSummary().getState().toString().toLowerCase().startsWith("open")) {
                                openOrders.add(order);
                            } 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }       
        return openOrders;  

Now, I am trying to change to Java 8 using Streams.

openOrders = orders.stream()
                        .filter(order -> Objects.nonNull(order))
                        .map(order -> order.getOrderSummary())
                        .filter(orderSummary -> Objects.nonNull(orderSummary))
                        .map(orderSummary -> orderSummary.getState())
                        .filter(orderSummaryState -> Objects.nonNull(orderSummaryState))
                        .map(orderSummaryState -> orderSummaryState.toString())
                        .filter(orderSummaryStateStr -> Objects.nonNull(orderSummaryStateStr))
                        .filter(orderSummaryStateStr -> orderSummaryStateStr.toLowerCase().startsWith("open"))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList<GetOrderResponseType>());
```

on the last statement I am getting Syntax error on token "(", Expression expected after this token.

Thanks,
Bandita Pradhan

Comment: The issue is this: `.filter(orderSummaryState -> orderSummaryState.toString())`.  Filter takes a predicate, which is a function that returns a boolean.  But you're returning a string.  It looks like what you probably want is a combination of `.map` and `.collect`, instead.

Comment: I changed to map. Now I get the error on very last statement while trying to add as List<GetOrderResponseType>

Comment: `Collectors.toList<GetOrderResponseType>()` should be `Collectors.<GetOrderResponseType>toList()` or just `Collectors.toList()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  `.map()` function changes the type of object stored in the stream. For instance, when you do `.map(order -> order.getOrderSummary())` you are changing the stream from `Stream<GetOrderResponseType>` to `Stream<OrderSummary>`. So on your last step when you try to collect the stream back to a `List<GetOrderResponseType>`, you can't because you have a `Stream<String>`, which is the string order summary state, rather than `Stream<GetOrderResponseType>`.

What you are trying to accomplish may be better done with a single filter, and passing in a method reference that does your filtering, like this:

```
List<GetOrderResponseType> openOrders = orders.stream()
    .filter(this::isOpenOrder)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And then define an `isOpenOrder` method as  such:

```
private boolean isOpenOrder(GetOrderResponseType order) {
    if (order == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (order.getOrderSummary() == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (order.getOrderSummary().getState() == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return order.getOrderSummary().getState().toString().toLowerCase().startsWith("open");
}
```

Comment: Thank you Andrew for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using 'map' correctly. If you have a stream of some objects of type T and you use

```
map(t -> t.toString())
```

then you get a stream of Strings, all the information about objects of class T is lost. So after your chain of maps and fiters you have just a stream of strings. You cannot magically convert them into list of GetOrderResponseType. You should keep the information about your type to the end, and then just do collect toList() without any type parameter, because toList() will automatically know the type of your stream.

Answer (score 0):

The filter takes a predicate which should return boolean, but below line try to return String. Hence, the mismatch error has been reported.

```
.filter(orderSummaryState -> orderSummaryState.toString())
```

Further, an order cannot be filtered and collected later into a list once you use a map as it returns a new stream of the results of the given mapper function.

```
   .map(order -> order.getOrderSummary())  // this returns a new stream
```